# ObjC - UITapGesture does not work for offscreen object in iphone4 screen with transform

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, hittest, screen-size

I have a complicated animation for a game app.
and because every animation there is a frame origin, thus, it is difficult for me to do auto layout across iphone 4 and iphone 5.

As my game starts building from iphone 5 screen size,
I made a transform of the Core View.

It really works for all views and all animations.
But for the tap gesture below iphone4 px (i.e. origin.y > 468)
those taps detections are lost.

Also,

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

does not get triggered by tapping on it.

Somehow the hittest does not trigger,
Is there any way to get around it?

Thanks every bros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by changing the bound of the app and somehow it works as it.
Thanks for your interest in this topic.